# How long can a Worker Role process set status to "busy" before getting killed?

Tags: windows, azure

I have a worker role process that want to stop processing new requests when it's too busy (e.g. CPU load > 80%, long disk queue, or some other metrics).

If I set the role status to "busy", will it get killed by Fabric Controller after busying for too long time? If yes, how long will it takes until the Fabric Controller kill the process?

I assume the process is still capable to receive/send signals to the Fabric agent.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leave an instance in the Busy status forever.  The only time Azure will take recovery action is if the process exits.  See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2013/02/28/heartbeats-recovery-and-the-load-balancer.aspx for some additional information.

Also, what is your worker role doing?  Setting the instance status to Busy will only take it out of the load balancer rotation so that new incoming TCP connections will not get routed to that instance.  But if your worker role is a typical worker role where it does background jobs (ie. sits in a loop picking messages up from a queue, or listening on an InternalEndpoint for requests coming from a front end web role) then setting it to Busy will have no effect.  In this scenario you would add logic to your code to stop doing work, but what that looks like will depend on what type of work your role is doing.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer, especially on TCP part.

Agree, the busy status is not very useful for Worker Role except for diagnostic purpose (monitoring status via Service Management API). My worker receive jobs from queue so setting it busy is useless.

BTW, what's the best practice for production/staging slot? Because the role itself has no idea on what slot it is in, the worker cannot switch between queues and pickup different jobs. It seems kind of useless except for Web Role.

Comment: You are correct, for worker roles with no external InputEndpoint the staging vs. production slot is largely irrelevant. The only aspect that would matter is if the worker role called out to an external resource with a whitelisted IP address.